# Can you draw arbitrary graphics in a (neo)vim buffer?

Tags: ascii-art

I'm looking for how, if possible, to draw arbitrary graphics in a vim buffer. The reason is that my git graph is too difficult to read:

```
* | 2021-02-11 [32a37ba] {Tama ...
* | 2021-02-11 [3ee4853] {Tama ...
* | 2021-02-10 [e1a262c] {Tama ...
|\| 
| * 2021-02-09 [883be01] {Tama ...
| * 2021-02-09 [8632108] {Tama ...
| *   2021-02-09 [e4ef3a1] {Tam...
| |\  
| | *   2021-02-07 [1330a96] {T...
| | |\  
| | * | 2021-02-07 [abcaf22] {T...
| * | | 2021-02-09 [aa45850] {T...
| * | | 2021-02-09 [f827bde] {T...
| * | | 2021-02-09 [60ee4db] {T...
| | |/  
| |/|   
| * | 2021-02-06 [0f6ac11] {Tam...
```

At FOSDEM this year, I was blown away by [Nick Black's presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq963c6Fl5E&t=11m35s), which is given entirely through a terminal buffer, even though it looks like a full-blown video file. So it seems as if the technology is ready to give vim arbitrary graphics, at least as long as you are running vim from a suitable terminal emulator.

There's a related question [here, but it is just asking how to blit images in the terminal.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97542/how-do-i-make-my-terminal-display-graphical-pictures) The answer to this question will likely depend on that one.

Comment: In part, it sounds like if you could port vim/neovim to not_curses, you could do a lot of really cool things :)

Comment: Obligatory disclaimer that I have no clue what the extent of this is (nor have I used it, nor did I write the code), but there's a [C plugin on Windows](https://github.com/skywind3000/vim-bgimg/blob/master/autoload/bgimg.c) that does background images in gVim. While I have no idea how to port any bit of that to Linux (or the terminal on either OS), that at least shows you can do some things, at least if you're willing to venture outside the terminal. There might be some terminal options too. To what extent you can use this, though, is an entirely different question, and one I can't answer.

Comment: of course, at one point, it might just be easier to port whichever Vim you use to not_curses and throw in some fancy rendering APIs. You might also get far just by messing around with multibyte characters instead of fancy rendering (at least depending on your end goal) - there's a number of characters that interconnect across multiple lines, like ▏(`\u258f`)

Comment: Wikipedia actually has a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements -- there's also a fullwidth slash (／), but it doesn't work well with emerging from the right side of 258f. There's also a demo (ish, it's probably functional, but proves that it can be done with unicode) of something like this using unicode characters [here](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/495#issuecomment-17480757) if that's more what you're looking for.

Comment: interesting. It's unfortunate it was written in such an arcane programming language; I was hoping it would just be some trivial replacements of characters the git log outputs, but unfortunately this approach is going to be difficult to port: `(cond ((and before-merge (eq merge (car trunkc)))(setq before-merge nil)(magit-pg-stradd output (magit-pg-getchar branchright colour) str)) (memq (car trunkc) trunk-merges) (magit-pg-stradd output (magit-pg-getchar down colour)` etc.

Comment: [This perl script](https://github.com/jwiegley/git-scripts/blob/master/git-forest) seems to use all the same connecting unicode block_elements, although the colors in the emacs plugin are much better.